# Can I directly call the function GeoFire uses to find nearby geohashes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, geofire

I am making an app that allows users to ask friends and people nearby questions. GeoFire makes it so much easier. However, the app users can also filter answers based on proximity (say within 1km). Since there could be hundreds of answers to each question and people really just occasionally need it, I don't want to store all the answers to the GeoFire node.

So is there a function I can call to find, from a list of locations like below, those that are within certain radius of a given location? I know there are ways to find distance between two geohashes. Just wonder if there is a more "GeoFirey" way.

```
answers:
    question1:
        user1:
            answer: yes
            longitude: 23
            latitude: 23
        user2:
            answer: no
            longitude: 34
            latitude: 34
        ...
```

Comment: I'm confused: isn't "find keys that are within certain radius of a given location" precisely what GeoFire does?

Comment: That's using a GeoFire query. I am asking can I do it without query, since I don't want to index every answers

Answer (score 0):

Finding keys that are within certain radius of a given location requires running a geo-query.

While you could certainly create your own geo-querying mechanism on top of the Firebase Realtime Database, you'd still need an index on the geohash values. So you'd just be re-creating GeoFire in that case.